# War file deployment in JBoss 4.2 server, with Maven repositories

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, maven-3, war

I am a first time maven user. The project I have needs to be deployed into JBoss 4.2 server as a war file.

I realized we can eliminate **Ant** if we are using **Maven**.

Previously I used to configure my build path and my jars location in build.properties file.
Now using Maven I am confused how to build a war file with referenced libraries are with Maven.

My directory structure is as follows:

[image: Directory Structure of Project]

My previous build.properties file was :

```
deploydir=C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy
userlib=C:/Jar/empty
warname=bala
```

My pom.xml for Maven is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.source.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>This is a sample project</description>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I am trying to build the war file by right clicking the project and "Run as - Maven Install".

I am getting error as follows.

```
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom (7 KB at 5.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom (11 KB at 22.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/19/maven-parent-19.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/19/maven-parent-19.pom (25 KB at 35.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom (15 KB at 30.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar (26 KB at 35.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom (11 KB at 22.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.10/surefire-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.10/surefire-2.10.pom (12 KB at 24.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/20/maven-parent-20.pom (25 KB at 49.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.jar (30 KB at 39.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom (5 KB at 10.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar (23 KB at 41.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ JavaServerFaces ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.pom (6 KB at 12.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/16/maven-shared-components-16.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/16/maven-shared-components-16.pom (9 KB at 17.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.jar (42 KB at 39.5 KB/sec)
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ JavaServerFaces ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ JavaServerFaces ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ JavaServerFaces ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ JavaServerFaces ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.9/maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.9/maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 3.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.9/maven-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.9/maven-2.0.9.pom (19 KB at 21.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/8/maven-parent-8.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/8/maven-parent-8.pom (24 KB at 29.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom (5 KB at 8.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.10/surefire-booter-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.10/surefire-booter-2.10.pom (3 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.10/surefire-api-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.10/surefire-api-2.10.pom (3 KB at 4.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.10/maven-surefire-common-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.10/maven-surefire-common-2.10.pom (4 KB at 8.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.pom (4 KB at 8.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom (9 KB at 16.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom (9 KB at 16.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.9/maven-artifact-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.9/maven-artifact-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 3.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.9/maven-project-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.9/maven-project-2.0.9.pom (3 KB at 5.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.9/maven-settings-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.9/maven-settings-2.0.9.pom (3 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.9/maven-model-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.9/maven-model-2.0.9.pom (4 KB at 6.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.9/maven-profile-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.9/maven-profile-2.0.9.pom (3 KB at 4.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.9/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.9/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.9.pom (3 KB at 5.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.9/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.9/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.9/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.9/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0.9/maven-core-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0.9/maven-core-2.0.9.pom (8 KB at 15.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0.9/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0.9/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 3.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.0.9/maven-reporting-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.0.9/maven-reporting-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 3.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0.9/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0.9/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 3.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.9/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.9/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.9.pom (3 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0.9/maven-monitor-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0.9/maven-monitor-2.0.9.pom (2 KB at 2.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.pom (4 KB at 7.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.3/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.3.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.3/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.3.pom (4 KB at 7.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/12/maven-shared-components-12.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/12/maven-shared-components-12.pom (10 KB at 18.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/13/maven-parent-13.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/13/maven-parent-13.pom (23 KB at 44.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom (13 KB at 25.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.pom (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.10/surefire-booter-2.10.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.10/surefire-api-2.10.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.3/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.3.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.10/maven-surefire-common-2.10.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.10/surefire-booter-2.10.jar (34 KB at 40.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.3/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.3.jar (31 KB at 23.1 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar (10 KB at 19.2 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.10/maven-surefire-common-2.10.jar (60 KB at 33.6 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar (220 KB at 91.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.10/surefire-api-2.10.jar (158 KB at 65.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\User-1\workspace\01mkyoungJSF\target\surefire-reports
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.10/surefire-junit3-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.10/surefire-junit3-2.10.pom (2 KB at 3.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.10/surefire-providers-2.10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.10/surefire-providers-2.10.pom (3 KB at 4.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.10/surefire-junit3-2.10.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.10/surefire-junit3-2.10.jar (26 KB at 46.8 KB/sec)

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ JavaServerFaces ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.pom (4 KB at 8.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0/plexus-archiver-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0/plexus-archiver-1.0.pom (2 KB at 3.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.17/plexus-components-1.1.17.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.17/plexus-components-1.1.17.pom (6 KB at 10.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/2.0.5/plexus-2.0.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/2.0.5/plexus-2.0.5.pom (17 KB at 32.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0/plexus-io-1.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0/plexus-io-1.0.pom (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.pom (2 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.pom (2 KB at 2.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.pom (12 KB at 22.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream-parent/1.3.1/xstream-parent-1.3.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream-parent/1.3.1/xstream-parent-1.3.1.pom (14 KB at 28.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.pom (2 KB at 3.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.pom (4 KB at 8.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/10/maven-shared-components-10.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/10/maven-shared-components-10.pom (9 KB at 17.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/9/maven-parent-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/9/maven-parent-9.pom (33 KB at 45.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.pom (6 KB at 10.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.12/plexus-1.0.12.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.12/plexus-1.0.12.pom (10 KB at 20.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.6/plexus-interpolation-1.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.6/plexus-interpolation-1.6.pom (3 KB at 6.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.jar (20 KB at 37.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar (25 KB at 20.3 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.jar (50 KB at 30.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar (33 KB at 28.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar (178 KB at 67.7 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar (422 KB at 141.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [JavaServerFaces] in [C:\Users\User-1\workspace\01mkyoungJSF\target\JavaServerFaces-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [55 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\User-1\workspace\01mkyoungJSF\target\JavaServerFaces-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.821s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 14 15:06:16 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project JavaServerFaces: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am not understand how to do war file deployment into JBoss 4.2 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `maven-war-plugin` cannot find the `web.xml` file.

My suggestion if you want to go with maven is to stick to maven conventions and particularly the [Maven Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

A simple war project would have the following directory layout:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    |   ├── java
    |   |   └── my
    |   |       └── package
    |   |           └── SomeJavaClass.java
    |   ├── resources
    |   |   └── my
    |   |       └── package
    |   |           └── UIMessages_en.properties
    |   └── webapp
    |       ├── hello.xhtml
    |       ├── welcome.xhtml
    |       └── WEB-INF
    |           └── web.xml
    └── test
        └── java
            └── my
                └── package
                    └── SomeJavaClassTest.java
```