# How to deploy .war file to JBoss AS 7 server using Maven?

Tags: maven, jboss

I have "pom.xml" file which is connecting to maven and checking out the code and creating a war file. Now I have to deploy the created war file to JBoss Application Server 7. Below is my `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.deploy</groupId>
   <artifactId>deploy-app</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>deploy-app Maven Webapp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <scm>
      <connection>scm:svn:http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</connection>
      <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk           /dev</developerConnection>
      <url>http://d-113017553/svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</url>
   </scm>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>deploy-app</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
               <username>keerthana</username>
               <password>keerthana</password>
               <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/co/src</checkoutDirectory>
               <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/co/src</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
               <goals>scm:checkout</goals>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.Final</version>
            <configuration>
               <jboss_Home>D:\Workspace\deploy-app\target</jboss_Home>
               <serverName>default</serverName>
               <fileName>target/deploy-app.war</fileName>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Please give me the steps to deploy my war file to the Jboss Server.

Comment: once check following link might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376011/war-file-deployment-in-jboss-4-2-server-with-maven-repositories

Comment: I get the following errors,

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.Final:deploy (default) on project deploy-app: Could not execute goal deploy on D:\Workspace\deploy-app\target\deploy-app.war. Reason: Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }'. java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://D-0190918:8080. The connection timed out
Pls help me

Comment: What version of Jboss AS do you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, use `bin/add-user.sh` to add **management** user.

Then, store that into your settings.xml.

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>myproject-prod<id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <properties>
            <myproject.deploy.pass.prod>mySecretPassword</myproject.deploy.pass.prod>
        </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Then, configure the `pom.xml`.

```
<properties>
    <jboss-as.deploy.hostname>localhost</jboss-as.deploy.hostname>  <!-- Where to deploy. -->
    <jboss-as.deploy.user>admin</jboss-as.deploy.user>
    <jboss-as.deploy.pass>${myproject.deploy.pass.prod}</jboss-as.deploy.pass>
    <plugin.war.warName>${project.build.finalName}</plugin.war.warName>
</properties>
```

...

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <warName>${plugin.war.warName}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            

        <!-- JBoss AS plugin to deploy the war. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
                <hostname>${jboss-as.deploy.hostname}</hostname>
                <username>${jboss-as.deploy.user}</username>
                <password>${jboss-as.deploy.pass.prod}</password>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>target/${plugin.war.warName}.war</fileName>
                </fileNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

and then simply...

```
mvn clean deploy;
```

This is reduced from one JBoss project, may contain typos, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try the above steps.

Comment: Can u please tell me what i have to add in the bin/add-user.sh?? I am new to maven and i am getting error in doing the above steps.

Comment: If you're deploying to a server running on your local box you don't need to add a user. You only need to add a user if you're deploying to a remote server.

Comment: `bin/add-user.sh` found in JBoss 7 HOME folder

Comment: <warName>${plugin.war.warName}</warName> - this is unnecessary, you're setting the value to its default

Answer (score 0):

- First, use bin/add-user.sh to add management user(admin/1234).
- Second add to pom.xml:

  ```
  <build>     
  <plugins>       
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.5.Final</version>
          <configuration>
              <hostname>localhost</hostname>
              <port>9999</port>
              <name>app_name.war</name>
              <username>admin</username>
              <password>1234</password>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```
- Three:  edit JBoss_Home/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml change the Ip address to 0.0.0.0:
  [image]
- Four, deploy using #clean install jboss-as:redeploy
  [image]

Comment: Hi add user in the server or in the remote box that we are going to deploy ? can you please tell i am facing a issue in that...