# How to deploy .jar file to JBoss EAP6 server using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a maven EJB projet whitch i want to deploy by maven command.
I can take the jar of that projet and put it into the folder deployement of my jboss server but i want to do that by maven.
I made some searchs and i found :

In the goals i can make : jboss-as:deploy.

In the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <filename>${artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</filename>                      
    </configuration>                
</plugin>
```

The errors whitch gives me are:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.7.Final:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project myapp: Could not execute
>   goal deploy on
>   D:\workspaces\myapp\target\myprojet-0.0.1.jar.
>   Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{ [ERROR] "operation"
>   => "read-attribute", [ERROR] "address" => [], [ERROR] "name" => "launch-type" [ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could
>   not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out

This is a part of the standalone.xml:

```
enter  <interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9998}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

I have a local Jboss Server. and i tried this (in the pom):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</filename>
                <username>test1</username>
                <password>Pass9584</password>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it manually first?

Comment: Is your JBoss running on localhost:9999?

Comment: to @khmarbaise : i copy the jar of my generated projet after cleaning and installing it by maven and i paste it into ...\jboss-server\standalone\deployments

Comment: @jHilscher : 
` <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9999}"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>`

Comment: Do you have an admin account set up for your JBoss? You might need the credentials: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357175/how-to-deploy-war-file-to-jboss-as-7-server-using-maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357175/how-to-deploy-war-file-to-jboss-as-7-server-using-maven)

Comment: @jHilscher : i tested what are in the url whitch you have given and it doesn't work.
I have an admin account

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP are you running? Can you ping localhost from a command line?

Comment: hi @James R. Perkins , i use Jboss EAP 6.3 and localhost is pinging from command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you changed the native management port to `9998`. That's what the plugin uses to connect to the server for management operations.

```
 <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9998}"/>
```

You'll need to add `<port>9998</port>` to your plugin configuration.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <filename>${artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</filename>
        <port>9998</port>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```